# Access a multilingual WordPress blog from multiple directories

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I need to access my multi-language blog on WordPress from different directories.

My landing page is placed in this way:

```
example.com => English
example.com/es => Spanish
```

I installed my blog in the directory `blog,` and I installed a WPML plugin to handle multilanguage.

Unfortunately, what I achieved is:

```
example.com/blog => English blog
example.com/blog/es => Spanish blog
```

How to make it accessible from `/es/blog`? Do I need another instance of WordPress? Maybe there are some settings? .htaccess? I tried many things, but I failed.

Comment: Maybe it's your settings in the table "wp_options" under siteurl and home?

Comment: not really, they are default there and I think it's replaced later by wp-config. I'm trying the solution with two different WordPress, I'm putting them now in subdirectories.